# Reply to messages in K-9 mail without going through the menu

Tags: k9-mail

In K-9 (latest version on Google Play, 4.403), is there a way to either:

- Add a Reply/Reply-All button to the bottom of the message details view
- A gesture to Reply/Reply-All in the message details view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the latest K-9 version (4.4x).
However, it is not yet available for all devices / countries.
I installed K-9 on my Galaxy S4, and it installed 4.2x, which is not the latest.

See this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43061020&postcount=1); there's a download link to the 4.4x APK, 
which you can install manually.
The newer version uses an actionbar which has a reply button.